# Call member function from executable

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement some functionalities in a gameserver that I have the PDB file.
All modification are coded in my DLL that I hooked.

```
I'm refering global functions using it pointer like this :

.cpp file
pXXX YYY = (pXXX) 0x00403B7F;

.h file
typedef <return_type_function>(*pXXX)(<args>);
extern pXXX YYY;
```

The problem happened when I tried to call a member function. I read something about referecing member function to be different.The functions that I used from Class 1 all worked, but when I tried to call the functions from Class 2, the gameserver crashed.

Why the functions from Class 1 worked? Maybe is because Class 1 have constructor Class 2 don't ? All functions are public.

Could someone help me?
Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C++ non-static member function is not just a regular function because:

- requires the implicitly passed "this" parameter
- may require a dynamic lookup for virtual methods

Also in C++ you cannot declare a "pointer to any method of any class that given an integer returns an integer". So **in theory** a pointer to a method could be just a small integer, describing which is the method you're interested in (given that the class is fixed and known at compile time).

In practice however for a non-virtual method in g++ (Linux 64-bit) seems that a pointer to method is just a pointer to a regular function that accepts an extra pointer parameter before all others, following the standard x86-64 abi.

For example in the class

```
struct Foo {
    int k;
    Foo(int k) : k(k) {}
    int square(int x) { return k*x*x; }
    int cube(int x) { return k*x*x*x; }
};
```

the code for `square` is just:

```
00000000004006d0 <_ZN3Foo6squareEi>:
  4006d0:   8b 07       mov    (%rdi),%eax ; get this->k in eax
  4006d2:   0f af c6    imul   %esi,%eax   ; times x
  4006d5:   0f af c6    imul   %esi,%eax   ; times x
  4006d8:   c3          retq
```

where `%edi` is the implicit `this` parameter and `%esi` is the input `x` parameter and the code is the same for a C function declared as

```
int meth(Foo *this_pointer, int x);
```

With g++ a method pointer is finally actually a pointer to the code of the function (in the specific case the value was `0x00000000004006d0`).

Note of course that this is just valid for this version of g++ on Linux 64-bit. Calling a generic method of a generic class is something that is conceptually impossible in portable C++ because the type of the class is part of the method signature so everything in this area is implementation-dependent.

I'd expect a similar approach also for other C++ compilers (using the real code address makes calling more efficient) but you'll need to check with your specific compiler/environment.

### An example with g++

As a simple example consider this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyClass {
    int x;

    MyClass(int x) : x(x) {
    }

    void dump(int y) {
        printf("dump() called: x = %i, y = %i\n", x, y);
    }
};

MyClass class1(1111);
MyClass class2(2222);

MyClass *getClass(int x) {
    if (x == 1) return &class1;
    if (x == 2) return &class2;
    return NULL;
}

void (MyClass::*aptr)(int) = &MyClass::dump; // NEEDED
```

compiled as a shared library with:

```
g++ -Wall -O3 -fPIC -shared mylib.cpp -o mylib.so
```

and consider this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    void *p = dlopen("./prg.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    printf("p = %p\n", p);
    if (p) {
        void *(*geti)(int);
        geti = (void *(*)(int)) dlsym(p, "_Z8getClassi");
        void (*dump)(void *, int);
        dump = (void (*)(void *, int)) dlsym(p, "_ZN7MyClass4dumpEi");
        printf("geti = %p\n", geti);
        printf("dump = %p\n", dump);
        if (geti) {
            for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                void *q = geti(i);
                printf("geti(%i) = %p\n", i, q);
                if (q && dump) {
                    printf("  calling dump on the instance:\n");
                    dump(q, 33);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compiled normally as a stand alone executable C program (gcc, not g++).

The program will load the C++ library and will call the `dump` method on two instances declaring them as normal C functions that accept the extra `this` parameter. Note however that

1. All this is **highly** non-portable, and may be it's something it doesn't work in more complex cases even with g++/gcc. Seems to work also mixing g++ and clang++ but it could be a coincidence for this simple case.
2. You need to know the address of the instances of the objects you wish to call methods of... here I've used a `getClass` function
3. You need to know the mangled name of the functions to call
4. May be not all method of the classes are exposed; for example I had to force it in this toy test because otherwise `dump` was simply not present at all in the shared library (see the "NEEDED" comment).

To sum it up... are you really really sure you want to get this dirty?

Comment: Why can't I declare a "pointer to any method of any class that given an integer returns an integer" ?

Comment: @Bruno: Because it's how the C++ language was defined. A method pointer is a pointer of a method **of a specific class** that must be known at compile time. I'm not saying it's the right thing or the only possible technical solution, but just what it happens to be the C++ language.

Comment: Thanks for all the information !! But I don't understand why the member functions from Class 1 that I declared as pointer-to-function worked.

Comment: @Bruno: may be it was a `static` member function? Those are just regular C functions with a funny name...

Comment: I just noticed that all methods are static. Thanks again.

Comment: Something like this example could work to call a member function?
http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/Pointers_to_memberfuncs.pdf

Comment: @Bruno: That is the regular C++ syntax to call a member function, but it's meant to be used within a program. If you want to call a member function in an external executable known the address you need something different. Using a C function pointer that simply has an extra `this` parameter could work (it would work with g++)

Comment: Hey, could you provide me some example of how to pass the extra this parameter?

Comment: @Bruno: I've added a complete example of a C program loading a C++ shared library and calling a method. May be it just seems to work but it's not... and for sure it's a violation of every standard in existence.